# Who was that specific goalkeeper who was so agressive he earned a red card?

Tags: football, goalkeeper

Somewhere between 1996 and 2002 perhaps when I was a child, I distinctly remember seeing a bald goalkeeper getting a red card in either one of the World Cups or European championships. Sadly I can't remember the exact details other than the goalkeeper was bald, and outright agressive. Who would fit such a description?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've checked every match from Euro 96, World Cup '98, Euro 2000, and World Cup 2002. I can only find one goalkeeper who was sent off at any of those tournaments: Belgian goalkeeper Filip De Wilde, who was sent off during a group match against Turkey at Euro 2000. He wasn't *quite* bald, but he certainly was aggressive (and prone to mistakes), if this footage of his Euro 2000 performance is anything to go by. I've timestamped it to start with the red-card incident.